# How to capitalize LaTeX3 sequence element in document input stream?

Tags: latex3, capitalization

How to capitalize LaTeX3 sequence element in document input stream? The problem with `\seq_item:N` I think, becaue it unexpandable.

```
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn


\seq_new:N \g_syllabus_kafname_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\kafname{ m }
 {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_syllabus_kafname_seq { #1 }
 }


\NewDocumentCommand{\thekaf}{ O{1} }
 {
     \seq_item:Nn \g_syllabus_kafname_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \firstcap { m } {   \text_titlecase:n  {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\kafname{aass}
\kafname{bbb}
\kafname{ccc}


\firstcap{\thekaf[2]} %Need Bbb

\end{document}
```

Comment: seq_item is expandable,  but thekaf is not.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, thank you. But if I write `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thekaf}{O{1}}` this one does not work with O{} parameter, but with m does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could put the formatting command inside the \thekaf command:

```
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn


\seq_new:N \g_syllabus_kafname_seq

\NewDocumentCommand\kafname{ m }
 {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_syllabus_kafname_seq { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__syllabus_kaf_format:n {}

\NewDocumentCommand{\thekaf}{ O{1} }
 {
     \__syllabus_kaf_format:n 
       {\seq_item:Nn \g_syllabus_kafname_seq { #1 }}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \firstcap { m } {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__syllabus_kaf_format:n\text_titlecase:n  
   #1
  \group_end: 
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\kafname{aass}
\kafname{bbb}
\kafname{ccc}

\thekaf[2],  \firstcap{\thekaf[2]} %Need Bbb

\end{document}
```